# ASP.NET MVC Jqgrid Edit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, edit

**SCRIPTS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllCategories", "Admin")',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['sno','Kategori Adı', 'Sıra No', 'Vitrin'],
        colModel: [
                { name: 'sno', index: 'sno', editable: false, hidden: true },
                  { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', editable: true },
                  { name: 'OrderNo', index: 'OrderNo', editable: true },
                  { name: 'IsShowcase', index: 'IsShowcase', width: 100, editable: true, sortable: false }
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false
        },
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        pager: jQuery('#gridpager'),
        sortname: 'CategoryName',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        id: "sno",
        width: 710,
        height: 300,
        editurl: '@Url.Action("_EditCategory", "Admin")'
    }).navGrid('#gridpager');
});
</script>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _EditCategory(CategoriesViewModel categoriesViewModel)
{
    Categories category = entity.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.sno == categoriesViewModel.sno);
    category.IsShowcase = categoriesViewModel.IsShowcase;
    category.Name = categoriesViewModel.Name;
    category.OrderNo = categoriesViewModel.OrderNo;
    try
    {
        entity.Categories.Add(category);
        entity.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }

    return PartialView(categoriesViewModel);
}
```

I debugged it. I cant post only sno of model(sno is the primary key of Model and uniq). Model is posted with parameters, but only sno is not posted.

How can I achieve this? THANKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that concerns me in your code is the `id` option which you use - jqGrid doesn't have such option. If that option was suppose to make jqGrid resolve the row id out of your model, than you should have use `jsonReader` for this purpose:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: 'sno'
    },
    ...
}).navGrid('#gridpager');
```

Now assuming that your rows ids are bound properly, you can use `prmNames` option to tell jqGrid that it should POST row id under *sno* name:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: 'sno'
    },
    prmNames: {
        id: 'sno'
    },
    ... 
}).navGrid('#gridpager');
```

This should resolve your issue.

P.S. Most probably you don't need *sno* column in your columns model (and columns names) definition as you use it only for row id.

Comment: Thanks. I m new about jqgrid. I dont know a lot of things about jqgrid properties. first code part is the enough for me.